# MySQL foreign keys with non-identifying relationships

Tags: mysql, innodb, foreign-key-relationship

All I need is to create 2 tabeles with next structure:
[image]

**The SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ds_cats` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `module_news_cats` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_module_news_cats_module_news_cats` (`parent`),
  KEY `fk_module_news_cats_ds_cats1` (`cat_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `module_news_cats`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_module_news_cats_ds_cats1` FOREIGN KEY (`cat_id`) REFERENCES `ds_cats` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_module_news_cats_module_news_cats` FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES `module_news_cats` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

**But when I try to insert first row to my table "module_news_cats", I recive next error:**

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`empty`.`module_news_cats`, CONSTRAINT `fk_module_news_cats_module_news_cats` FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES `module_news_cats` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Question:
How I can create table which will have an index with non-identifying relationship to the anther index in the same table? Some rows will have parents, and some not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to allow NULLs in `module_news_cats.parent`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `module_news_cats` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent` int(11) NULL,               -- Change this
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_module_news_cats_module_news_cats` (`parent`),
  KEY `fk_module_news_cats_ds_cats1` (`cat_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

and then if there isn't a parent, create the row with a NULL in `parent`.

Comment: if all values fullfill the foreign key constraints later you can also turn foreign key checks off temporarily, Insert your data and turn them back on.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'parent' field cannot be empty (NULL) if you insert a record, which means that every record you insert should refer to a parent ID (which is impossible if there are no entries in your table yet).

If you make the 'parent' field in the module_news_cats table nullable:

```
ALTER TABLE `module_news_cats` CHANGE `parent` `parent` INT( 11 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

you should be able to insert records that have no parent ID associated (just supply NULL instead of a value).

Answer (score 1):

You could make the parent column in the module_news_cats table nullable.

Then for rows that have no parents populate the parent column with null.